# Winpcap driver function calls

Tags: c++, windows, winpcap

My `C++` application uses `Winpcap` for various things (mostly learning right now).

How can I check that `Winpcap` is installed, to throw an error on application start-up if it's not?

Also, can anyone shed some light on how `Winpcap` driver functions are called?  I know I include `pcap`.h to call the functions, but how are they relayed to the `OS/Driver`?  It's not like `WINAPI` calls or `SYSCALLs` is it?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile and link your executable with winpcap on your machine, and it is then executed on a system where winpcap is not installed, the user will get a typical "program can't start because such and such is missing". Like this:

[image]

To alleviate this you can just assume that winpcap is present by

- Bundling winpcap with the installation of your software, subject to any licensing considerations your software might have.
- Asking the user to install winpcap on their own, before, or immediately after the installation of your software.

With such setup these your users will be more aware of what might be the problem when they encounter these errors.

To avoid the Windows error message box itself you can,

- Work with winpcap dynamically by explicitly loading it with `LoadLibrary()`, getting the method addresses with `GetProcAddress()` and bailing out if it can't be found.

I believe this is how Wireshark is doing it, or at least was doing it in the past.

For the latter it can also help if you can check if the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WinPcapInst` exists (it was once the recommended way to check for winpcap presence on the development mailing list) even before you try to LoadLibrary() to make sure that there is a proper install on the system. You can also check for the presence of this key in the installer of your software if it comes with one.

Note that this last option of working with winpcap dynamically is the least convenient one. If you are just experimenting you should follow the official guide. You didn't say what compiler you are using, nevertheless the official way of working with winpcap is outlined [in this document](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapsamps.html).

Generally winpcap interacts with the driver asynchronously but as a user of winpcap you should stick to the official interface and not call the driver directly. Here's a high-level diagram of how it works. I took it from the [NPF driver internals manual](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__NPF.html) webpage. You are encouraged to read it, and follow-up with specific questions.

[image: Source: www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__NPF.html]

Comment: "I believe this is how Wireshark is doing it, or at least was doing it in the past."  Yes, that's how Wireshark does it.